# Can I create customizer setting that can handle plugin shortcode?

Tags: theme-development, shortcode, theme-customizer, sanitization, get-theme-mod

Can I create a customizer setting which will handle a shortcode from a plugin? Do I violate and rules or guidelines in WordPress theme development?

If it's possible what is the best way to sanitize the shortcode data from my customizer setting?

Comment: Hi there, did you end up doing this? How did it go?

Comment: What is your objectives. Needs more details.

Comment: You couldn't use short code within theme. But, In plugin you'll do it. What do you mean short code sanitization? If you provide the textarea control to add short code from customizer then you can use the do_shortcode. But, need more details to know what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably best to render the shortcode on output by running it through `do_shortcode()`

Comment: This answer could use some explanation. Why is your solution probably best?